# ThreeJS - OBJLoader "Cannot read property 'uniforms' of undefined

Tags: javascript, three.js, loader

I'm trying to use three.js to import and render an object I made. Everything was find, I even succeded to apply a wireframe texture.

But i wanted to apply a Point cloud texture [(here)](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/PointCloudMaterial) but either it just display a color on my object either i get an error like writte non the tittle

my code is like that

```
                var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
            loader.load( 'obj/moimeme2.obj', function ( object ) {

                object.traverse( function ( child ) {

                    if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {

                        child.material = new THREE.PointCloudMaterial( {color: 0x6FF060 } );
                    }

                } );

                /*object.scale.y = 5;
                object.scale.x = 5;
                object.scale.z = 5;*/
                scene.add( object );

            }, onProgress, onError );
```

I'm kinda a beginner in JS and i don't really get what is the problem this

Thank you for reading !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Point cloud material is for point cloud geometry. Not for regular geometry.

Comment: Is it possible to transform a regular geometry from an obj to a point cloud geometry ?

Comment: If you only use the vertices of your object then you have a point cloud (as long as you have many vertices). Take a look at this example http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_raycasting_pointcloud.html

Comment: thank you for you anwsers ! It seems a bit complicated for me but i"ll try to understand =)